# apply inline css to rails

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails

I wish to apply CSS in inline rails code.

```
<%= form_for @wishlist, html: { class: 'ajax_form', id: 'change_wishlist_accessibility' } do |f| %>
<%= f.radio_button :is_private, true %>&nbsp;<%= Spree.t(:private) %>
<%= f.radio_button :is_private, false %>&nbsp;<%= Spree.t(:public) %>
```

<% end -%>
I want to apply `margin-left: 600px;` tot the form.

How can I do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<%= form_for @wishlist, html: { style: "margin-left: 600px;",class: 'ajax_form', id: 'change_wishlist_accessibility' } do |f| %>
```